# How to make an image center itself when size of the div is increased

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to fix an image to a popup window , My problem is the image is getting stretched to the whole div ,

The div where I am applying is getting the width and height from JQuery. 
 HTML

```
<div id="portfolio-detail" style="width: 745px; height: 655px; top: 22px; display: block;">
    <img class="portfolio-close" src="assets/images/cancel-button.png">
    <div class="viewimg" style="position:relative;display:block;width:100%;height:100%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin:0 ;"> 
        <img class="folioimg" style="position:absolute;width:100%" data-foliothumb="1" src="assets/gallery_crop_1.jpg">---&gt;</div>
</div>
```

The CSS is something like this

```
.about-slider-container {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 25px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#portfolio-detail {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Just curious. How your code is related to jquery?

Comment: When you say "stretched" do you mean it loses its aspect ratio? And, if, so do you want it to stretch to the available width but still retain that aspect ratio? I'd start by removing the height attribute.

Comment: @Vikram, what image do you want to be centered the image with class="folioimg" or class="portfolio-close"

Comment: And yes... good point from @DmitryPoroh - there's no jQuery here :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a position to your .about-slider-container.

```
.about-slider-container {
  position: relative; //or something that suits you
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 25px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#portfolio-detail {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  z-index: 9999;
}
```